# Setting Manual FPS in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

is there any way to set a manual FPS in andengine?? I am not talking about limiting FPS. I want to set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it.
You can set a maximum FPS, but the minimum FPS depends on the device and what background processes are running on it.

You could technically do it by setting max FPS to 1, but I don't think I need to explain how silly that would be.

Comment: Yes. I find the solution to the problem. There isnt any need to set FPS Manually.